# Jquery delete element by double click

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, click, double

Jquery drag and drop question
 I want to delete some elements that are inside a div container. My script is like this : i drag the element into #deleteArea and the element is out. The script :

```
  $("#deleteArea").droppable
     ({
         drop: function(event, ui) { 
            alert('in');
         deleteImage(ui.draggable,ui.helper); 
         }, 
         over: function() {
                   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#cedae3');
            },
             out: function() {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
            },
        });
```

and

```
function deleteImage($draggable,$helper)
         {
         params = 'id=' + $draggable.attr('id');

         $.ajax({
         url: 'delete.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: params,
          success: function(msg){  
                                   }
         });
         $helper.effect('transfer', { to: '#deleteArea', className: 'ui-effects-transfer' },500);
         $draggable.hide();
         }
```

Now i want to remove elements just by double click. I try starting from the script above this little code :

```
  $('.produse').dblclick(function(event, ui) { 
            alert('in');
         deleteImage(ui.draggable,ui.helper); 
         });
```

but i recive "ui is undefined" and i dont know what to do. please help

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing parameters to the click handler correctly.

In this piece of code:

```
$('.produse').dblclick(function(event, ui) { 
        alert('in');
     deleteImage(ui.draggable,ui.helper); 
     });
```

you have not declared the parameters to the anonymous function appropriately.  If you look at the [jQuery doc for `.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/), there are two ways of calling it:

```
.dblclick(handler(event))
```

or

```
.dblclick([eventData,] handler(event))
```

You are using neither of those.

If you want to pass some data to the dlbclick handler, it would work like this:

```
$('.produse').dblclick({uiData: ui}, function(event) { 
        alert('in');
     deleteImage(event.data.uiData.draggable, event.data.uiData.helper); 
     });
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NUU8s/